# Adding bootstrap to github pages repository.

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, github

I'm trying to add bootstrap as a submodule to github pages repo, getting symlink errors, anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Jekyll?

GitHub Pages sometimes incorrectly thinks something is a Jekyll site when it's not. If it's not, adding an empty file named .nojekyll to the root of the repository should fix it.